# Function Interposition in Linux (write function)

Tags: c, linux

Please how can I recover the buffer of the original write?

```
size_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count)
{
    static size_t (*write_func)(int, const void *, size_t) = NULL;

    /* get reference to original (libc provided) write */
    if (!write_func)
    {
        write_func = (size_t(*)(int, const void *, size_t))
                     dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "write");
    }
    return  write_func(fd, buffer, sizeof (buffer));
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "buffer of the original write"?

Comment: i would like to get the buffer "const void *buf" because I want to change it before sending

Comment: Hello,

The server sends a character (buffer of size 1) write (socketserveur, buffer, 1).
With linux interposition mechanism for write function, I changed the buffer size, 
i add another charactar to the buffer

The client was configured to receive a character read (socketclient, buffer, 1);
Do I have to apply the interposition mechanism to the read function also?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

One of the most efficient way to perform your augmentation is to slice out the bytes you want to change in the original buffer, and splice in your deltas. These are pasted together, and you use `writev` to write everything out.

```
struct iovec v[3];
v[0].iov_base = buf;
v[0].iov_len = position_of_new_data;
v[1].iov_base = new_data;
v[1].iov_len = new_data_len;
v[2].iov_base = (const char *)buf + beginning_of_the_end;
v[2].iov_len = count - beginning_of_the_end;
return writev(fd, v, 3);
```

This should work fine for blocking I/O. For non-blocking I/O, you will have more work to do to hide the fact that the `write` call was intercepted. Or, you could just flip the descriptor to blocking, and flip back to non-blocking before returning.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count)
{
    static size_t (*write_func)(int, const void *, size_t) = NULL;
    if (!write_func)
        write_func = (size_t(*)(int, const void *, size_t)) dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "write");

    // buf is const so, in order to change it, we need to make a copy:
    char tmp[count+1];  // <- it might be safer to use malloc here
    memcpy(tmp,buf,count);

    // modify tmp here
    tmp[count]='a';

    return  write_func(fd, tmp, count+1);
}
```

Please let me know, if that's what you wanted to do.

Comment: hello :) thank you so much for help, i try to add a char in the end of the buffer but it didn't work

Comment: size_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count)
{
    static size_t (*write_func)(int, const void *, size_t) = NULL;
    if (!write_func)
        write_func = (size_t(*)(int, const void *, size_t)) dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "write");

    // buf is const so, in order to change it, we need to make a copy:
    char tmp[count];  // <- it might be safer to use malloc here
    memcpy(tmp,buf,count);

    // modify tmp here
    
    tmp[sizeof(tmp)+1]='a';
  
    return  write_func(fd, tmp, count);
} have you an idea please ? it display only the original message without the char "a"

Comment: i try also this code:char buffer[100]="cc";
   int i;
   int j=0;
   for(i=strlen(buffer);i< strlen(buffer)+strlen(tmp);i++)
   {buffer[i]=tmp[j];
    j++;
   } but it display only a part of the buffer which has a size=the size of original message only